# Whats the best way to convert an NSString to an NSInteger based on an array of values?

Tags: objective-c, ios, type-conversion

I want to convert characters into integers based on predetermined values, for example:

```
a = 0 
b = 1
c = 2
d = 3
```

etc...

Right now I'm doing it with an If/Else If, I just want to know if there is a faster/better way I should be doing it because the list of conversions may get quite long.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
-(NSInteger)ConvertToInt:(NSString *)thestring {
    NSInteger theint;
    if([thestring isEqualToString:@"a"] == YES){
        theint = 0;
    } else if ([thestring isEqualToString:@"b"] == YES){
        theint = 1;
    } //etc...

    return theint;
}
```

This works fine, but as I said, if it makes more sense can I create an array with all the key/values then just run through that to return the integers?

Please provide examples as I'm a beginner with Objective C/iOS. I come from Web languages.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the help everyone. I used taskinoors answer but I replaced the NSDictionary which was giving error messages with this:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"a",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"b",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"c", nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unichar ch = [thestring characterAtIndex:0];
theint = ch - 'a';
```

Note that, `'a'` with a single quote is character `a`, not string `"a"`.

If the values are not regular like your example then you can store all predefined values into a dictionary. For example:

```
"a" = 5;
"b" = 1;
"c" = 102;

NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:102], nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

theint = [[dic valueForKey:thestring] intValue];
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what to do with that. Can you show me how to make it a function that I can pass the string "a" into and have an Integer returned. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I need to use strings because I will also have values such as "ab" to pass in that will need to return an Integer.

Comment: @tsdexter if you don't understand this example, you should rather learn Objective-C and C better.

Comment: @H2CO3 He wants to be able to use _strings_ not just single characters as his key.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, I do need to learn Objective C properly but once I have this piece I'm pretty well done the current project so it's not quite in my timeframe to learn it from the basics right now.

Comment: @tsdexter, if you need to use input like "ab" and irregular values for them then you can map them in a dictionary. Please check the edit.

Comment: @taskinoor Thanks. I can work with this. Much appreciated. I'll get back shortly with the results.

Comment: @mydogisbox, my first answer is working with strings as keys, it is not using characters as keys. It will work if string keys and values are regular like the example posted in the question. However, OP has confirmed that he needs strings with multiple characters and I have edited the answer to work with that.

Comment: @taskinoor My comment was directed at H2CO3.  I saw nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: @taskinoor the NSDictionary line you gave me is giving an error, I'm using     NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:102] forKeys:@"a", @"b", @"c"]; and it's saying 'Extraneous ']' before ';' and tells me to replace the closing square bracket with "" and then that gives another error.. Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Thanks. I got it working using dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys instead. See edit for syntax. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @tsdexter, sorry there was a syntax error in my old answer. You need to pass arrays to `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` method. Edited now. Also you can use `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep some flexibility in what strings map to what integers, and your integers run from 0 to n-1 where you have n unique items in the array, you could do something like this:

```
-(NSInteger)ConvertToInt:(NSString *)thestring {
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];
    NSInteger theint = [arr indexOfObject:thestring];
    return theint;
}
```

Now this will build the array each time, which would be very inefficient, the optimal way would be to build the array once in your class, and then just use a reference to that array with the indexOfObject method call.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. However, although I can fill the array in numerical order, it would be preferable to assign the integers for each array item as some cases the integers won't be in order or will not having corresponding strings so I'd have to stick in dummy data for the missing ints. It would also be easier for me to fill the array in the order of my data (which the integers are not in order). Any advice on how I should go about that?

Comment: I think his intention was to build a sort of cypher, where he could pass in a string like "aryls" and get 1, 18, 25, 14, 19. Is that right @tsdexter?

Comment: In that case, you would want to go with an NSDictionary as @taskinoor suggests above.

Comment: @MichaelDorst My original intention was actually simpler. I would only need one return per string and then I planned to call it many times. However, I do have strings such as "aa", "ab", "ac" etc that each need an Int value as well.. However, what you suggested might work better - is there a way I can pass in "aa\nab\nac" and get back 3 integers that I can then loop through and process?

Comment: @tsdexter I'm not sure what you mean. You want one integer from "aa", one from "nab", and one from "nac"? How would that integer be computed? And what do you mean "3 integers that I can loop through and process?" Theoretically you can loop through and process any array of integers.

Comment: @MichaelDorst No sorry. I am use \n as a separator. The strings are aa, ab and ac separated by \n

Comment: @tsdexter Oh okay. So how do you want the integers that correspond to "aa" "ab" and "ac" to be computed? Would it be 11, 12, 13, or 2, 3, 4?

Comment: There is no pattern. I'd have to assign an integer for every string. But basically, I am going to loop through the array and send each string, get an int and then do something depending on the int returned. So if I can send the whole string and return all the ints at once, then I can loop through the returned ints and process them. Would that be better for performance or the same as I'm doing now do you think?